# About Datepicker?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(

  /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
  function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true, //this option for allowing user to select month
      changeYear: true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" //this option is for display in dd-mm-yy format
    });
  }
);
```

This is my input code:

```
<label>Date Of Birth:*</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker">
```

From this code I am not getting the years before 2007. So how can I get the past years?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `yearRange` option to set the selectable range:

Hardcoded: `yearRange: "2000:2020"`

Relative: `yearRange: "-100:+0"`

The default is: this year - 10 : this year + 10 => this is why you can select only from 2007.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
yearRange:"minYear:maxYear",

yearRange:"-yearFromCurrentYear:+yearFromCurrentYear"
```

Code Example:

```
$(document).ready(
  /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
  function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      changeMonth: true, //this option for allowing user to select month
      changeYear: true, //this option for allowing user to select from year range
      yearRange: "1900:2100",
      dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" //this option is for display in dd-mm-yy format
    });
  }
);
```

Fiddle goes [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/aoa21hxj/)